# Controlling elements after dynamically creating them

Tags: jquery

After dynamically creating an element with this:

```
            $('#btnAddBanner').click(function () {
            var uid = new Date().getTime(),
            newBanner = '<li class="ui-state-default bannerBlock"><div class="beVisible"><input type="checkbox" name="chkBanner_' + uid + '" id="chkBanner_' + uid + '" checked="checked" /></div><div class="beDelete"><img class="btnDelete" src="/images/btn_delete.png" alt="Delete Banner" /></div><div class="beBanner"><img src="/images/NewBannerTemplate.jpg" width="285" height="81" border="0" alt="" /></div><div class="beName"><input type="text" id="txtBannerName_' + uid + '" class="EditBox1" placeholder="Temp Text" value="(type banner name here)" /></div><div class="beFileName">File Name: <input type="text" id="FileName_' + uid + '" class="EditBox1 EditBoxAltText" style="width: 197px;" value="" /></div><div class="beUpload"><a href="#"><img src="/images/icons/disk.png" alt="Upload" /></a></div><div class="beStart">Start Date: <input type="text" id="StartDate_' + uid + '" class="EditBox1 EditBoxAltText" style="width: 80px;" value="" /></div><div class="beEnd">End Date: <input type="text" id="EndDate_' + uid + '" class="EditBox1 EditBoxAltText" style="width: 80px;" value="" /></div></li>';
            $('#sortable').append(newBanner);
            $('.chkBanner_' + uid).screwDefaultButtons({ checked: 'url(images/btn_light_on.png)', unchecked: 'url(images/btn_light_off.png)', disabled: 'url(images/btn_light_off_dim.png)', disabledChecked: 'url(images/btn_light_on_dim.png)', width: 33, height: 35 });
            $('.txtBannerName_' + uid).val("(type new name here)");
            return false;
           });
```

Although this button does create a new LI element, I'm having a hard time controlling many of the elements inside once created.  The "delete" button works - but only when using the live() function:

```
        $('.btnDelete').live('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });
```

The ScrewDefaultButtons plug-in does not get called though.  And the text boxes themselves do not behave the same as LI elements I manually write in for texting purposes.  For example, the basic hover css replacement doesn't work on the text fields. What am I missing?  It has to do with binding - but all I can figure out is how to deal with any click functions (like the delete button).  Everything else though doesn't respond as "normal" elements already on the page.

*UPDATE*
Here is what I've added so that the mouseover, etc works:

```
            $(".EditBox1").live("mouseover mouseout focus blur", function (event) {
            if (event.type == "mouseover") {
                $(this).addClass('EditBoxHighlight');
            } else if (event.type == "mouseout") {
                $(this).removeClass('EditBoxHighlight');
            } else if (event.type == "focusin") {
                $(this).addClass('EditBoxSelect');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('EditBoxSelect');
            }
        });
```

This works great.  Now all that is left is the checkbox image replacement.  I'm sure this has more to do with the plugins syntax.  How does one format the live() function with a non-standard call such as:

```
$('input:checkbox').screwDefaultButtons({ checked: 'url(images/btn_light_on.png)', unchecked: 'url(images/btn_light_off.png)', disabled: 'url(images/btn_light_off_dim.png)', disabledChecked: 'url(images/btn_light_on_dim.png)', width: 33, height: 35 });
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` and `bind` assign an event to elements that *already exist* at the time of calling. `live` in constrast, also adds the event if an element matching the selector is added later. That's why the button works when you use `live`.

An alternative would be to call `click` or `bind` after the element is created. That is a better solution in terms of performance, but the gain isn't that big for small pages. Also, it's a little more complex. You got to make sure you don't add the event as well to elements that already have one, or they will actually be bound to two event handlers.

[edit]

The problem with the selectors `'.chkBanner_' + uid` and `'.txtBannerName_' + uid`, is that they are class selectors, while the elements only have an id. Either make `'chkBanner_' + uid` a class of the element, or change the selector to `'#chkBanner_' + uid`.

Comment: Right - which is why the DeleteBanner button works.  But how do I handle all the other elements (txtBox, checkbox, etc); trying similar syntax fails.

Comment: I think it's because of an error in the selectors. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for catching that - simple mistake (I swapped them many times and simply forgot).  Now that that is done, it's still causing issues with resetting the checkbox.  This clearly has to do with just setting the LIVE() function on non-standard calls - such as:
$('input:checkbox').screwDefaultButtons({ checked: 'url(images/btn_light_on.png)', unchecked: 'url(images/btn_light_off.png)', disabled: 'url(images/btn_light_off_dim.png)', disabledChecked: 'url(images/btn_light_on_dim.png)', width: 33, height: 35 });

Any ideas on how to format such a line?

Comment: I think you'd better close this question and ask that in a different question. That will attract new attention of others who may be able to help, and allows you to do some formatting on your code as well.